# Memory leak in DatePickerDialog. How to identify what is the problem?

Tags: android, leakcanary

I am using [this `MaterialDateTimePicker` library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) in my app. I have a problem with finding the root cause of the leak. `DatePickerDialog` is leaking based on what the log shows. I am not sure if the lib has a problem but I think I am doing something wrong.

I have a `View` that displays the current date. The user is able to click it, then `DatePickerDialog` displays. Then s/he selects a day and click on the **ok** button of the `DatePickerDialog`. I receive the date, format it and then present it. After a few seconds, Leak Canary lib says hey you leaked. It would be great if you can tell me what's wrong with my code.

So, this is my custom widget.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import com.atco.forsite.R
import com.atco.forsite.screens.utility.DatePickerOFIState.NOW_FUTURE
import com.atco.forsite.screens.utility.DatePickerOFIState.PAST_NOW
import com.jakewharton.rxrelay2.PublishRelay
import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog
import java.util.Calendar

enum class DatePickerOFIState {
    PAST_NOW,
    NOW_FUTURE
}

class DatePickerOFI(
    private val context: Context,
    private val fm: FragmentManager,
    private val state: DatePickerOFIState
) : DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    /**
     * Subscribe to this observer in order to be notified when the result is ready.
     */
    val relay: PublishRelay<Calendar> = PublishRelay.create()

    private val datePicker: DatePickerDialog

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "DatePickerDialog"
    }

    init {
        val now = Calendar.getInstance()
        datePicker = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                this,
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        datePicker.version = DatePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_2
        datePicker.accentColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryBlue)
        datePicker.setOkColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
        datePicker.setCancelColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))

        when (state) {
            PAST_NOW -> datePicker.maxDate = now
            NOW_FUTURE -> datePicker.minDate = now
        }
    }

    fun show() {
        datePicker.show(fm, TAG)
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePickerDialog?, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
        relay.accept(calendar)
    }
}
```

There is nothing special in my `Activity`. I open the `DatePickerDialog` like this:

```
class SafetyExchangeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_safety_exchange)

        val datePicker = DatePickerOFI(this, supportFragmentManager, DatePickerOFIState.PAST_NOW)
        datePicker.relay.safeSubscribe(createDefaultObserver(logger) {
            setReportDate(this)
        })

        etReportedDate.setOnClickListener {
            datePicker.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Leak trace:

```
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager class
│    Leaking: NO (InputMethodManager↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static InputMethodManager.sInstance
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager instance
│    Leaking: NO (DecorView↓ is not leaking and InputMethodManager is a singleton)
│    ↓ InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
├─ com.android.internal.policy.DecorView instance
│    Leaking: NO (LinearLayout↓ is not leaking and View attached)
│    mContext instance of com.android.internal.policy.DecorContext, wrapping activity com.atco.forsite.screens.records.safetyExchange.SafetyExchangeActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    Parent android.view.ViewRootImpl not a android.view.View
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ DecorView.mContentRoot
├─ android.widget.LinearLayout instance
│    Leaking: NO (SafetyExchangeActivity↓ is not leaking and View attached)
│    mContext instance of com.atco.forsite.screens.records.safetyExchange.SafetyExchangeActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    View.parent com.android.internal.policy.DecorView attached as well
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ LinearLayout.mContext
├─ com.atco.forsite.screens.records.safetyExchange.SafetyExchangeActivity instance
│    Leaking: NO (Activity#mDestroyed is false)
│    ↓ SafetyExchangeActivity.datePicker
│                             ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.atco.forsite.screens.utility.DatePickerOFI instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ DatePickerOFI.datePicker
│                    ~~~~~~~~~~
╰→ com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
​     key = dd153a49-8e66-45f7-8736-16342134e7f6
​     watchDurationMillis = 5297
​     retainedDurationMillis = 297

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 29
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.2
App process name: com.atco.forsite
Analysis duration: 8193 ms
```

Comment: Since some of the code is missing here so I am making a guess, You might still be subscribing to relay even the dialog is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the leak trace, I think the source of the issue is this line

```
private val datePicker: DatePickerDialog
```

in `DatePickerOFI` class.

As a solution, I think you need to nullify `datePicker` instance variable once your job is done i.e the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: You are right. I changed the instance creation of the DatePickerOFI in a way to nullify it when the job is done and Show() method creates its instance again if the user decided to change for the second time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It probably should be `var`:

```
private lateinit var datePicker: DatePickerDialog
```

And it should be deconstructed `onDestroy`:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    datePicker = null;
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I believe the problem was in my DatePickerOFI class. I got Leack notification when I was in the activity. Therefore nullify it in activity did not help.

Comment: @Hesam it might still report a _potential_ leak, but it won't leak when the Activity is destroyed. Think one can `null` it in both situations, the one option is just the soonest and the other one the latest.